# Maven not find dependency in Nexus

Tags: java, maven

My pom file for the project has the following distribution management tag

```
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>confiz-repo</id>
        <url>http://10.10.10.230:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

i use mvn deploy and that gives me a success. So i know my artifact has been deployed successfully. Now my settings.xml file is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" 
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <pluginGroups>
  </pluginGroups>

  <proxies>
  </proxies>

  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>confiz-repo</id>
      <username>admin</username>
      <password>admin123</password>
    </server>
  </servers>

  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <!-- The id of this mirror and the server instance above needs to be the same!-->
      <id>confiz-repo</id>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
      <url> http://10.10.10.230:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
    </mirror>
    <mirror>
      <!-- The id of this mirror and the server instance above needs to be the same!-->
      <id>confiz-repo</id>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
      <url> http://10.10.10.230:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>

  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <!--Enable snapshots for the built in central repo to direct -->
      <!--all requests to nexus via the mirror -->
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>confiz-repo</id>
          <url>http://central</url>
          <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </releases>
          <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
      </snapshots>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
      <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <id>confiz-repo</id>
          <url>http://central</url>
          <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </releases>
          <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>


  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>

</settings>
```

Now when i include the dependency for the first project into my second project and run mvn clean install maven complains

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project merchant: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.onestopspot:merchant:apk:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.confiz.abc:my-artifact:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT in confiz-repo (http://10.10.10.230:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/) -> [Help 1]
```

what am i doing wrong ?

**EDIT** - I can see my artifact deployed in nexus. So i am right in saying that the mvn deploy works correctly. But the path `http://10.10.10.230:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/` from which nexus is trying to read does not contain my artifact.

Comment: just a guess: try 1st: clean install on the project that has to be deployed. and secondly (after install), deploy it

Comment: "So i know my artifact has been deployed successfully" - no, you don't. Go to Nexus with your browser and look for your artifact under http://10.10.10.230:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/ -- if it's not there, you know that you didn't really get a successful deploy, so you'll need to update your question with the output from Maven while it's doing the deploy.

Comment: If you *do* see it there, your `groups/public` repository is misconfigured. However, out of the box it should reference your snapshots repository, so I'm betting that you didn't actually deploy correctly.

Comment: Also, you should have separate repositories in your `distributionManagement` for releases and snapshots. Especially since Nexus allows you to limit what artifacts get uploaded to what repository.

Comment: How can i configure groups/public to reference my snapshot repo ?

Answer (score 0):

Your second project is trying to grab artifact of first project from nexus which isn't exist there

1. You might want to deploy snapshot on nexus
2. If you don't want to do 1. run `mvn clean install -o` on second project in offline mode

Comment: some repositories do 'wierd' things with snapshots... maybe hes repo deos not allow snapshots, or clears them just after deploy... He should try with full version IMO.

Comment: Is my settings.xml file valid ? I think that my distribution management is pointing to one repo while the settings.xml file is trying to read to another repo

Comment: if it is available in http://10.10.10.230:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots then it would be availbale